# Angular 2 ngFor first occurence undefined

Tags: angular

I'm trying Angular 2 and I'm facing a weird issue that I don't understand.

I make a simple todo list and when I execute my app I have this error message :

[image: Error message from Chrome console]

I don't understand why the first occurence iterated is undefined. My array is hardcoded so I don't find out why there is this issue.
Here is the code for this application :

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { TodoNavComponent }   from './app.todo-nav';
import { TodoListComponent }   from './app.todo-list';
import { TodoComponent }   from './app.todo';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ TodoNavComponent, TodoListComponent, TodoComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ TodoNavComponent, TodoListComponent, TodoComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.todo-list.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { TodoService } from "./app.service";

@Component({
    selector: "todo-list",
    template: `
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <todo *ngFor="let todo of todos" [todo]="todo"></todo>
            </ul>
        </div>`,
    providers: [TodoService]
})
export class TodoListComponent {
    todos: any[] = [
        { name: "Do shopping", done: false },
        { name: "Get some gaz for my car", done: true },
        { name: "Download last season of Game of Thrones", done: false }
    ];

    constructor(private service: TodoService) {
        service.todoAdded$.subscribe(
            todo => {
                this.todos.push(todo);
            }
        );
        service.todoRemoved$.subscribe(
            todo => {
                this.todos = this.todos.filter(
                    (value, index, array) => {
                        return todo.name !== value.name;
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
}
```

app.todo.ts

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, Input  } from "@angular/core";
import { TodoService } from "./app.service";
import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component( {
    selector: "todo",
    template: `
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <i class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-remove" (click)="remove()"></i>
            {{todo.name}}
        </li>`,
    providers: [TodoService]
})
export class TodoComponent implements OnDestroy {
    @Input() todo;
    subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private service: TodoService){
        this.subscription = service.todoAdded$.subscribe(
            todo => {
                this.todo = todo;
            }
        );
    }

    remove() {
        this.service.removeTodo(this.todo);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Here is the rendering :

[image: Rendering result]

What did I miss ?
I don't understand why it occures just for the first occurances and not the others.

Thank you !

Comment: This fix for this error is explaned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291111/angular-2-first-item-in-array-missing-using-ngfor

Answer (score 0):

1. You should include TodoService inside the NgModule providers. If you inject TodoService inside the TodoComponent and TodoListComponent they will both get their own copy of the service. It means that if you add something to the TodoService inside the TodoComponent it will not show inside the service injected in TodoListComponent.
2. You should move subscribing to services from constructor to OnInit hook. Constructors are supposed to be lean. Here's what the Angular 2 docs say:

> We don't fetch data in a component constructor. Why? Because experienced developers agree that components should be cheap and safe to construct. We shouldn't worry that a new component will try to contact a remote server when created under test or before we decide to display it. Constructors should do no more than set the initial local variables to simple values.
>
> When a component must start working soon after creation, we can count on Angular to call the ngOnInit method to jumpstart it. That's where the heavy initialization logic belongs.
>
> **Remember also that a directive's data-bound input properties are not set until after construction. That's a problem if we need to initialize the directive based on those properties. They'll have been set when our ngOninit runs.**

Comment: Ok, for the service using I just follow the documentation, I'm using the OnInit now but that doesn't solve my undefined issue on the first iteration. When I subscribe to my service in the constructor I found it because the service was give to my through the parameter of the constructor, now where I can find the service ?

Answer (score 0):

Object?.name will help u if u want to loop

Comment: That just create more errors. I just want to understand why the first item of a hardcoded array is not correctly iterated by the loop directive.