# ionic 2 template running before subscribe data

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm grabbing data from a remote URL and passing it to my template. However on the inital view of the page it's not showing the first index of the object, only the second. When I leave the tab and go back to it, it then shows both objects. And on the inital load when i log the object they are both there.

After looking here: [Angular 2 First Item in Array Missing using *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291111/angular-2-first-item-in-array-missing-using-ngfor)

I feel it may have to do with missions.ts being an entry component. But when I remove it then I get an error about a missing factory.

missions.ts

```
missions: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public http: Http, private storage: Storage) {
    this.http.get('http://hunt/api/getMissions').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
            this.missions = data;
            console.log(data);
        }); 
  }
```

Missions.html

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let mission of missions" (click)="selectMission(mission.id)">
    {{ mission.name }}
  </button>  
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this.http.get in the ionViewDidLoad lifecycle event. It sounds like the observable is returning the first result before ionic is ready to render the result. This will delay subscription of the observable until ionic is ready to render the template.

Comment: I have tried that and it still doesn't load the first element.

even in a defined array without the http.get it still doesn't show the first one.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who had this issue it was actually a formatting one. For some reason the scroll-content div wasnt applying the margin top and it was hiding the info behind the top nav bar. I just added the margin manually and all is good.